# How this SMPSU start up and working on CC mode?

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply

I want to understand how my switching power supply work and how to modify value for CC and CV mode.
The SMPSU I got is almost identical to this reverse engineer schematic. ([link here](http://danyk.cz/reverz45_en.html))
I alo inserte the schematic image to confirm accessibillity.
The question is.

1. How this circuit start up? It needed voltage supply to controller ICs where it came from?
2. How the current control work in this design? It seem very different and more complicare than the circuit  from datasheet.
   [image]

This circuit provided by tl494 datasheet
[image]
for datasheet circuit I can find CC mode set point by make both side of error amp equals. From inverting input it got 1V from voltage divider and non-negative side, it got 1V from 0.1R resistor which mean current must flow 10A at CC mode.

Comment: In what way is the constant current control more complicated? Both have a resistor for current sense, a reference and a built in op-amp for the purpose.

Comment: The circuit initially gets a little power from the secondary - enough for it to start up properly.

Comment: @winny I edit my question to answer your comment.

Comment: @Andyaka so the little current must flow through primary side right? please tell me which path the current flow.

Comment: Through the 150 kohm resistors I suspect.

Comment: Notice the start-up resistors 2x150k/1W at the half-bridge transistor bases

Comment: It’s still unclear what major difference in the CC you are seeing. The value is different?

Comment: @winny how to calculate CC setpoint from reverse engineer schematic?

Comment: CC setpoint is equal to around \$ \Large Isc \approx \frac{V_{REF}\frac{1k\Omega}{1k\Omega + 100k\Omega}}{3.9m\Omega} \approx \frac{50mV}{3.9m\Omega} \approx 13A \$

Comment: @G36 But... How????

Comment: Notice the TL494 "ground" is connected "after" R_sens resistor, so we have a "floating ground", Thus, the noninverting input (pin 16) measures the voltage drop across R_sens resistor. A similar technique is used in linear power supplies. So that the voltage drop across the sense resistor does not affect the output voltage.

Comment: _”How to to calculate?”_ is vastly different from _”It seem very different and more complicare than the circuit from datasheet.”_ Which is it? Have you tried to hand-calculate it? Read the application note? Simulated it?

Comment: @winny I feed bad to say this. I just don't understand that circuit so I can't setup the equation to solve. Please give me some clue.

Comment: I would suggest you aid your understanding by reading the application note for that PWM IC in particular, or any other which uses current sense resistor for CC, and/or simulating it.

Comment: @winny you see the positive input of error amp connect to ground via 1k resistor and negative input connect to voltage divider which impossible to get lower voltage than ground. So I get confused and I need help.  I read the datasheet and I have no problem with it.

Comment: Ok, I notice that voltage signal from R_sense is negative so I can solve from that.

Answer (score 1):

At start up the TL494 is dead and primary of the drive transformer has a high impedance across it .Main switch halfbridge transistors  Q1 Q2 are biased slightly into class A due to the 150K bias resistors.They now have gain and form an oscillater due to positive feedback provided by the current overwind on the secondary of the drive transformer .The frequency of this prospective oscillation is on this circuit determined by main transformer saturation .The duty cycle of this start up oscillation is close to 50% ,in other words there is only a small amount of dead time .After a few cycles the TL494 activates because it now has Vcc .The TL494 now controls the power supply via the drive transformer primary .Output current is sensed along with output voltage and fed into the TL494 control loop in an orthodox manner .Under current limiting the average DC output voltage falls but Vcc which is peak rectified should stay relatively constant so the TL494 still runs .This old circuit was really clever in its day.It could be tarted up for greater reliability ,lower switching losses and outperform a lot of modern stuff .

Comment: For the love of god, can you please stop putting space before comma and period?

Comment: Can you explain current control loop? Snd setpoint calculation?